# Does the sentence 'Come out into the world' make sense?

Tags: grammar

I made the sentence like this. The sentence is 'Come out into the world'
Somebody always stayed at home because he doesn't want to make friends.
And his mom said "Come out into the world. Make a good friend."
Does the sentence 'Come out into the world' make sense?

Comment: It makes perfect sense! It means "**Go out and see the world, talk to people, travel and so on.**"

Comment: I agree, but I don't hear that often. Also, don't forget parallelism (he didn't). Stayed and said are in their past forms.